# Is it possible to do a "reverse" mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /product.cgi?id=$1 [L]
```

The above will execute example.com/product.cgi?id=* when url example.com/id/* is requested by the user. I would like the other way around,

i want to display to the user example.com/id/* when example.com/product.cgi?id=* is requested. Keeping in mind that example.com/id/* does not exist on the server, it would work line an alias. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your .htaccess to do the reverse.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /product\.cgi\?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /id/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /product.cgi?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is redirecting to `example.com/full/internal/path/to/document/root/id/1` 1 being one char only, even if there is more. I've tried something like you suggested but that would redirect to the correct URL but it was giving me the error "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: Ok try it now. I modified the rewriterule to add `/`

Comment: Seems to be working but i'm having the issue withe one char only thing, id value is a string of variable length

Comment: oops, fixed that for you. I updated the condition line.